# How can i get all my user files using Forge Data Management API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

We need to get all the root hubs, projects and folders for a user with Forge Data Management API, just like we do with Dropbox API:

[Dropbox API Reference](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm)

Does anybody from Autodesk know how to get all items from the users, without having to enter all folders, projects and hubs?

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to recursively list files on all subfolders, this is not natively implemented. [This .NET sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample) implements it on the UI tree, see the [tree controller class](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample/blob/master/data.management-csharp-sample/Controllers/DataManagementTreeController.cs).

That's an interesting feature from the Dropbox SDK, but more like a SDK feature, not the API.

Comment: Thanks augusto, but this can be a amazing feature to new autodesk updates, in dropbox this help a lot. And don't stress the server with many requests